# What's the difference between using th and lua commands to run a lua script?

Tags: lua, torch

Is there a difference in executing .lua files written for torch using `th` and `lua`?

On the server I'm using, I can't run the `th` command, but I can `import torch` inside the python interpreter (I'm assuming that this is because pytorch is installed but not torch itself).

I'm wondering if I can just run `lua scriptname.lua` instead of `th scriptname.lua` like instructed here: https://github.com/jwyang/JULE.torch

Comment: Probably `th` has some non-standard libraries already loaded by default.

Comment: I think that `Torch` is based on `luajit`, so I'd say using `lua` wont be possible that easily. If I remember correctly, the installation also puts a `qlua` executable next to the `th` binary. You can just import all the `th` libraries you need when using it. Plus, unlike `th`, it lets you create qt interfaces very easily, without having to handle threads etc.